# What is the difference between "aloof" and "standoffish"?

Tags: meaning

The meaning of aloof in the dictionary is: *not friendly or forthcoming*.

The definition for standoffish is: *distant and cold in manner*.

What is the difference between these two words? To me they look the same.

Comment: Sometimes words are pretty much the same.  Personally I'd attribute a slightly more "above this" tinge to "aloof" but they are very close words... that share many synonyms. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/standoffish

Comment: What @Tom22 said. *Aloof* has a connotation of being above others. *Standoffish* is more being apart from others. Otherwise, they mean pretty much the same.

Comment: what @Drew said.

Comment: They mean pretty much the same.  "Aloof" is more formal linguistically, while "standoffish" is not as "clinical" in its implications.

Comment: Stand made by (a) fish?

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, *aloof* is much more likely to be applied to men than to women, whereas *standoffish* is somewhat more likely to be applied to women than to men. This effect can be seen here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+aloof%2Che+was+standoffish%2Cshe+was+aloof%2Cshe+was+standoffish&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20aloof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20standoffish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20aloof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20standoffish%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Standoffish has more of a negative connotation, the subject being unsocial or even contemptuous (OED), whereas aloof means simply apart or at a distance.

Raymond Chandler uses both words in his personal correspondence:

"I am standoffish with strangers..." (1 Jan 1948)

"What on earth happended between this rather cool, aloof woman and me?" (3 Feb 1958)

An example of aloofian separateness in a poem by Paul Muldoon, "Princess and the Pea":

"Her lying there, extravagant, aloof / Like cream on milk."